# ESP8266 (ESP01) module has 1 MBit (approx 128 Kbytes) of flash memory. Then why EEPROM.begin(SIZE) has max allowed 4096 Size?

Tags: flash, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am using ESP8266 (ESP01) module with 1 MBit of flash memory. I want to store large amount of data into that flash memory.

From my perspective,

1 MBit of Flash => 1048576 Bits => 131072 Bytes (approx. 128 Kbytes)

But when I started to study EEPROM.begin(SIZE) function, I came to realize that, maximum I can pass 4096 value as a SIZE. See below code. SPI_FLASH_SEC_SIZE is a macro with value 4096.

```
if (size > SPI_FLASH_SEC_SIZE)
    size = SPI_FLASH_SEC_SIZE;
```

Now my question is how to access remaining memory. Or I am making mistake in calculating Flash momory space?

Comment: use SPIFFFS, not eeprom; it's way better anyway, having a file interface instead of a binary one.

Comment: @dandavis - Thanks. Will check for SPIFFS.

Answer (score 2):

SPI_FLASH_SEC_SIZE is set to 4096 because that's the sector size. This does not indicate the size of the flash chip itself. There is a sketch here that shows getting the flash size along with what the flash size on the IDE is set to in order to ensure that the IDE settings match what the chip is. https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/esp8266/examples/CheckFlashConfig/CheckFlashConfig.ino